# Swift2のコメントドキュメンテーションの配布方法について

Tags: swift2

Swift言語向けに静的ライブラリーを作成しようと考えています。

Swift2のコメントをドキュメント化して配布したいのですが、どのようにして配布するものなのかわからず困っています。

どういった方法がありますでしょうか。

イメージとしては、Javadocのようにmylib -1.0.0-javadoc.jar のような感じにしたいと考えています。そしてXcodeのユーティリティエリアに表示されるクイックヘルプとして表示されるようにしたいのです。
なお、ライブラリーにはソースを含めたくありません。

使用する Xcode は 7 で、コメントは Markdown 記法を採用しようと考えています。静的ライブラリーのプロジェクトは Cocoa touch Framework で作成します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常のドキュメントコメントの書式に則ってコメントを書けば、フレームワークでもXcodeのクイックヘルプに表示されるようになります。

ドキュメントコメントの書式については、以下のURLが参考になるかと思われます。

Swiftのドキュメントコメント - Qiita  
http://qiita.com/hironytic/items/12589b4735f4c95eec0c

以下、簡単に試してみました。

・フレームワーク側のクラス

```
import UIKit

/// テスト用のクラス
public class JunkTestClass {

    /// テスト用のイニシャライザ
    public init() {
    }

    /// テスト用のプリント関数
    public func testPrint() {
        print("testPrint: ")
    }
}
```

・フレームワークを読み込んで使用
[image: フレームワークのクイックヘルプが表示される]

ドキュメントを別に作成するのであれば、jazzyが有名でしょうか。

GitHub - realm/jazzy: Soulful docs for Swift & Objective-C  
https://github.com/realm/jazzy

Realmはもちろん、Parseなどでも使われています。

RealmSwift Reference  
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/

Parse Reference  
http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/